# how to split some part of a long equation in next line

Tags: equations

How do I split some part of my equation to the next line?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lefteqn{P_{n_i}(e,(t+1)) = p_{n_i}(e,t)+\eta_{n_i}[\bar{U}_{n_i}(e)\\
   &  -\bar{U}_{n_i}]p_{n_i}(e,t)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: It is more correct to give minimal Compiliable (working) example.

Answer (score 1):

Prоbably like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P_{n_i}(e,(t+1)) = p_{n_i}(e,t)+\eta_{n_i}[\bar{U}_{n_i}(e)\\
   &  -\bar{U}_{n_i}]p_{n_i}(e,t)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried like that but gives an error "misplaced alignment tab character &" @Olga K

Comment: @roshni - the code shown above doesn't generate this error message. How does your code differ from what's shown by @Olgka?

Comment: Seems there is no any mistake, I gave the picture above, see.

Answer (score 1):

For such a cases package `amsmath` or `mathtools`, which enhance amsmath provide environments `multline` and `multlined`. With latter one you can obtain:

[image]

with following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% only for show equation alone
\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{multlined}[44mm]
P_{n_i}(e,(t+1)) 
 = p_{n_i}(e,t)+\eta_{n_i}[\bar{U}_{n_i}(e)\\[1ex]
     -\bar{U}_{n_i}]p_{n_i}(e,t)
    \end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In your MWE you use `\lefteqn{ ...}`. Where you find this? If you like to have left aligned equation in whole document, than you should use option `fleqn` in document class like:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
```

or in package `amsmath` or in `mathtools` for example

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
```